# PHPUnit server side coverage with curl requests

Tags: php, curl, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I have some tests for an old PHP app, and it have inline tests and some curl requests to test APIs. The PHPUnit coverage, using Xdebug, isn't detecting the curl requests.

Is there a way to follow this curl requests and detect de coverage on the server side? The server side is the same machine, and I know that xdebug accepts something like XDEBUG_SESSION id on http requests when debugging, and I thougth that maybe there is something similar on code coverage, as the phpunit uses xdebug internally to get the code coverage.

Those tests aren't using Selenium, just raw curl requests, but we can modify those curl requests to add headers, cookies, or anything we need to add this coverage.

Here is an example of the requests:

```
    $url = "http://localhost/api/";
    $mensaje = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
        <collectionList xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"collectionList.xsd\" version=\"1.0\">
              <input collection_id=\"test_1\" />
        </collectionList>";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $mensaje);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

We're running unit test using this:

```
/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal -dxdebug.mode=coverage /usr/share/php/phpunit.phar --coverage-clover unitTest_xml --configuration configuration.xml --teamcity
```

The server part is running with the xdebug enabled, too, and in php.ini we have this configuration:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.idekey=docker
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.mode=develop,debug,coverage
```

And in every request, first thing we do is:

```
xdebug_start_code_coverage( XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED | XDEBUG_CC_DEAD_CODE );
```

And we end with a:

```
xdebug_stop_code_coverage(false);
```

As xdebug documentation says, ending with coverage with a "false" allows to continue in another session, but it doesn't work on my case. I presume that phpunit already started the coverage session, and doesn't support concurrency.

Thanks!

Comment: "isn't detecting the curl requests" - what does that mean? That the API you call isn't part of the coverage? That's not possible through cURL, as this uses a seperate request that PHPUnit can't follow

Comment: It means that code coverage doesn't detect anything on the server side. It is the same machine, and I know that xdebug accepts something like XDEBUG_SESSION id on http requests when debugging, and I thougth that maybe there is something similar on code coverage.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is XDebug itself running on the cURL requests?

Comment: If I understand correctly the phpunit test makes a http request with curl to a local endpoint where some code you are testing is executed. And you would like that the originating phpunit coverage includes all the code that was executed inside the curl request?
Not sure if this is possinble as phpunit uses https://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage#xdebug_start_code_coverage to gather coverage data and that can't cross process boundaries. Try to call the code you are testing directly from phpunit.